# Viewing inbox in mutt

Tags: mutt, email-client

I have installed fetchmail, procmail and mutt. I am able to see my sentmail but I am not able to see my inbox. 
This is my ~/.muttrc file

```
# Boring details
set realname =Aparna

set from = kdasaparna@gmail.com

set use_from = yes

set envelope_from ="yes"

set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"


# If not set in environment variables:
set spoolfile = /var/spool/mail/aparna

#======================================================#
# Folders
set folder="~/Mail"                # Mailboxes in here

set record="+sent"                 # where to store sent messages

set postponed="+postponed"         # where to store draft messages

set move=no                        # Don't move mail from the spool.

#======================================================#
# Watch these mailboxes for new mail:
mailboxes ! +Fetchmail +slrn +mutt
set sort_browser=alpha    # Sort mailboxes by alpha(bet)

#======================================================#
# Order of headers and what to show
hdr_order Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer \
          To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:
ignore *
unignore Date: From: User-Agent: X-Mailer  \
         To: Cc: Reply-To: Subject:

#======================================================#
# which editor do you want to use? 
# vim of course!
set editor="vim -c 'set tw=70 et' '+/^$' " 

set edit_headers          # See the headers when editing

#======================================================#
# Aliases

set sort_alias=alias     # sort aliases in alpha order by alias name

#======================================================#
# Odds and ends
set markers          # mark wrapped lines of text in the pager with a +

set smart_wrap       # Don't wrap mid-word

set pager_context=5  # Retain 5 lines of previous page when scrolling.

set status_on_top    # Status bar on top.

push <show-version>  # Shows mutt version at startup

macro index,pager I '<shell-escape> fetchmail -v<enter>'

 set mbox_type=Maildir



 macro index c "<change-folder>?<toggle-mailboxes>" "open a different folder"

 macro pager c "<change-folder>?<toggle-mailboxes>" "open a different folder"

set mbox_type=maildir

set mbox="~/mail/inbox/"

set spoolfile="~/mail/inbox/"

set folder="~/mail/"

set record="~/mail/sent/"

set postponed="~/mail/postponed/"

set editor="vim"

set include=ask-yes

set sendmail="/usr/sbin/ssmtp"
```

My ~/.fetchmailrc file:

```
poll pop.gmail.com                   
with proto POP3                      
user 'kdasaparna@gmail.com'        
there with password '*'        
is 'Aparna Karuthodi' here                              
mda "/usr/bin/procmail -d %T"        
options                                                             
no keep                                 
ssl                                  
sslcertck                            
sslcertpath /home/aparna/.certs/
```

My ~/.promailrc file

```
PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin 
VERBOSE=off  
DEFAULT=/var/spool/mail/aparna    
MAILDIR=$HOME/mail            
LOGFILE=$HOME/.procmaillog  
# Recipes below this comment:

:0:
* ^TOmutt-user
mutt
```

Comment: Do the incoming messages actually get to your spool file? Is it empty? Do you see any messages if you call `mutt -f /var/spool/mail/aparna`?

Comment: @Juancho I am getting no such file or directory

Comment: @Juancho: there is no folder called aparna inside /var/spool/mail

Answer (score 2):

I recognise [one of my old guides](http://www.andrews-corner.org/mutt.html) being used here:). mutt would normally create this file for you but you can create the file manually and then set the correct permissions and owners. First create the file:

```
sudo touch /var/spool/mail/aparna
```

Then set the correct permissions:

```
sudo chmod 660 /var/spool/mail/aparna
```

Finally make sure the ownership is correct:

```
sudo chown aparna:mail /var/spool/mail/aparna
```

Test this with **ls**, on my own system I see the following:

```
andrew@ilium~$ ls -l /var/spool/mail/andrew
-rw-rw---- 1 andrew mail 30743 Jul 17 15:30 /var/spool/mail/andrew
```

and you should see something similar when using:

```
ls -l /var/spool/mail/aparna
```

And this should be enough to get you going...

Comment: But still my problem is not solved. I am getting such an error:
/home/aparna/mail/sent/: Not a directory (errno = 20)

Comment: Mind you I note that you have specified:

 set folder="~/Mail" 

So try running:

touch ~/Mail/sent

And hopefully this will be enough...